# SQL Server 2005 - SSIS Package Won't Execute

Tags: sql-server

Environment:

- Windows Server 2003 R2 Standard x64
  Service Pack 2
- SQL Server 2005 SP2
  (9.00.3077.00) Enterprise Edition
  (64-bit)

Trying to install and execute an SSIS package on a development environment, getting the following error:

> Executed as user: NIHR\svcaccsqlagent. ....00.3042.00 for 32-bit  Copyright (C) Microsoft Corp 1984-2005. All rights reserved.    Started:  11:50:53  Error: 2009-06-02 11:50:56.28     Code: 0xC0010018     Source:       Description: Error loading value "PCRN Data Update Batch Log0SSIS log provider for T" from node "DTS:LogProvider".  End Error  Could not load package "E:\PCRN_SSIS\PCRN Data Update Batch.dtsx" because of error 0xC0010014.  Description: The package failed to load due to error 0xC0010014 "One or more error occurred. There should be more specific errors preceding this one that explains the details of the errors. This message is used as a return value from functions that encounter errors.". This occurs when CPackage::LoadFromXML fails.  Source:   Start...  Process Exit Code 5.  The step failed.

Any ideas?
The same package is working fine on a production environment, I can't tell what's different.

Comment: Anything special about it?  DTS? JET DB Access?

Answer (score 1):

Does your SSIS package contain a DateTime type variable?

Read this Microsoft support article:

[You receive an error message when you try to load an SSIS package that contains a DateTime type variable in SQL Server 2005](http://support.microsoft.com/?scid=kb%3Ben-us%3B918038)

> This problem occurs because the value
>   of the DateTime variable is saved in
>   string format when you save the SSIS
>   package. However, the string
>   representation of the DateTime
>   variable is based on the date format
>   that is specified in the Windows
>   locale. Therefore, when you try to
>   load the SSIS package on a computer
>   that has an incompatible locale date
>   format, the operation fails.

**Solutions:**

Manually update the DateTime type string in the SSIS package to use the slash (/) character as the date separator

*or*

Update the date separator in the Windows locale setting to be identical to the date separator of variables in the SSIS package file.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are trying to run a 32 bit package on a 64bit server, by default the 32 are not [installed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141766.aspx)

> on a 64-bit computer, selecting Integration Services during Setup installs only the 64-bit runtime and tools. If you have to run packages in 32-bit mode, you must also select an additional option to install the 32-bit runtime and tools:

```
* If the 64-bit computer is running the x86 operating system, select Business Intelligence Development Studio or Management Tools - Complete.
* If the 64-bit computer is running the Itanium operating system, select Management Tools - Complete.
```

Answer (score 1):

If you run the dtexec command manually from a command line passing it the same parameters that the SQL Agent is passsing it you should get more error information.